# jquery how to select the nth-child of the current TD in a dynamic table

Tags: jquery

This is probably simple for some of you, but I'm having trouble with it.  I want to get the value of the first TD in the TR of the TD that has a checkbox that has been checked.
The line of code to alert the CSS of the nth-child is just my last attempt at selecting the TD.

```
$('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
        //alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
          data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error alert(errorThrown); 
          }
        });
        alert($(e.target:nth-child(-10)).css);
      });

<td class="dupegroup">#dupe_group_number#</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="UserIDList" value="#userid#" /></td>
<td><a href="#request.controlURL#individuals/?fa=viewIndiv" target="_blank">#userid</td>
<td>#lastname#</td> 
<td>#firstname#</td> 
<td>#nickname#</td>
<td>#companyname#</td> 
<td>#address1#</td>
<td>#zipcode#</td>
<td>#state#</td>
<td>client</td>    
<td align="center"><input class="notdupe" type="checkbox" name="indivID" value="#userid#" checked /></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$firstTD = $(this).parent().siblings().first()
```

Comment: Yay! This did it. 

  $firstTD = $(this).parent().siblings().first()
  alert($firstTD.text());

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
        //alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
          data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error alert(errorThrown); 
          }
        });
        alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
      });
```

Comment: That givess me the value of the checkbox (which is the userID).  I need the text of the first TD in the row.

Answer (score 1):

```
$td_you_want = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').first();
```

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').first('td').text() gives me the text of the TR (all of the TDs).

Comment: My bad; updated answer. Using `closest` instead of `parent` is IMO more reliable because you just might end up wrapping that checkbox in some other tags later on.

Answer (score 1):

In your click handler:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first')
```

Comment: This gives me [object Object] in the alert.

Comment: Yes, because that is the object.  You need to extract the data you want from that object.